# Prove that there are two values to the third side,one of which is $m$ times the other.

Tags: trigonometry, triangles

Let $1<m<3$.  In $\triangle ABC$, if $2b=(m+1)a$ and $\cos A=\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{\frac{(m-1)(m+3)}{m}}$, prove that there are two values to the third side, one of which is $m$ times the other.

---

$\frac{b}{a}=\frac{m+1}{2}>1$
We need to prove that $c$ has two values, one of which is $m$ times the other.
Applying cosine law,
$$c^2=a^2+b^2-2ab\cos C$$
I am stuck here as $\cos C$ is not given.  Is there any other method possible for solving this question?

Comment: Have you tried using $a^2=b^2+c^2-2bc\cos A$ ?

Comment: As @learner suggests, use $a^2 = b^2 + c^2 - 2 b c \cos A$. The algebra will get a little messy, but stick with it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By the law of cosines,
$$a^2=b^2+c^2-2bc\cos A=\left(\frac{(m+1)a}{2}\right)^2+c^2-2\cdot\frac{(m+1)a}{2}\cdot c\cdot \frac 12\sqrt{\frac{(m-1)(m+3)}{m}}$$
from which we have
$$\frac{(m-1)(m+3)}{4}a^2=-c^2+\frac{(m+1)ac}{2}\sqrt{\frac{(m-1)(m+3)}{m}}$$
Now dividing the both sides by $a^2$ and letting $x=c/a$ give
$$\frac{(m-1)(m+3)}{4}=-x^2+\frac{(m+1)x}{2}\sqrt{\frac{(m-1)(m+3)}{m}},$$
i.e.
$$x^2-\frac{(m+1)}{2}x\sqrt{\frac{(m-1)(m+3)}{m}}+\frac{(m-1)(m+3)}{4}=0$$
and so
$$\begin{align}\frac ca&=x\\&=\frac 12\left(\frac{(m+1)}{2}\sqrt{\frac{(m-1)(m+3)}{m}}\pm\frac{(m-1)}{2}\sqrt{\frac{(m-1)(m+3)}{m}}\right)\\&=\frac 14\sqrt{\frac{(m-1)(m+3)}{m}},\quad\frac m4\sqrt{\frac{(m-1)(m+3)}{m}}\end{align}$$
so, we have
$$c=\frac a4\sqrt{\frac{(m-1)(m+3)}{m}},\quad\frac {ma}4\sqrt{\frac{(m-1)(m+3)}{m}}$$
from which the claim follows.

Comment: I do not understand how you got $$\frac{(m-1)(m+3)}{4}a^2=-c^2+\frac{(m+1)ac}{2}\sqrt{\frac{(m-1)(m+3)}{m}}$$ from first equation.@mathlove

Comment: @VinodKumarPunia: Sorry, I omitted details. I did $a^2-((m+1)a/2)^2=(1-m)(m+3)a^2/4$, and multiply the both sides by $-1$.

Comment: @mathlove: If you make the (rather unmotivated) substitution $$c =\frac{1}{2} a x \sqrt{\frac{(m - 1)\;(m + 3)}{m}\;}$$ the quadratic for $x$ reduces *very* nicely. And, since the $x$-roots are simply multiples of the $c$-roots, the fact that one $x$-root is $m$-times the other automatically implies the same relation between the $c$-roots.

Comment: @Blue: That's very nice. Thank you for pointing that out.